# Why is the layout on my android tablet different now?

Tags: support, mobile-web

Last week the layout of Stack Overflow on my **Samsung Galaxy Tab** suddenly changed from **normal-web** (green/orange) to a **more mobile layout** with different colors (blue/orange) and a different order of the page items.

What memo or setting did I miss?

System info:

- user agent is Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; nl-nl; GT-P1000 Build/FROYO) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
- screen size is set to 800 x 1183

---

**errata**: Seems that that is in display-mode.portrait where the **real** resolution is **600 * 1024**, according [to the specs](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytab/2010/). (Did not have time to research that properly last night so I dumped above dimensions from [this site](http://www.myip.nl/)). Somehow the software manages to deliver a different resolution, I don't know if that is the *browser*, the *JavaScript* or my *system settings* faking something.

Comment: [You missed this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98215/stack-exchange-mobile-theme-beta-starts-now)

Comment: ....Yes that! Why?

Comment: You mean why they decided to do a mobile theme?

Comment: I did not spent $500 to have a mobile experience ;) Where are the docs on this?

Comment: Just click (or whatever) "full site" on the bottom.

Comment: not saying that mobile site is bad, on the contrary it looks great! But the device is big enough to handle the "full site". :) thanks for the tip.

Comment: We'll tweak the user agent and treat Galaxy as desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tablets are a tad odd, they straddle the line between mobile and desktop.

So, here's what I've decided to do.  If we think you're browsing with a tablet (which is a bit unpleasant to figure out actually; you'd think people would put `tablet` in the user-agent, but noooo) we'll serve you the standard non-mobile theme.

However, we'll also put the "switch to mobile" link in the footer just like we do for mobile devices that have disabled the mobile theme.

Comment: Thank you! I am certainly not dissatisfied whit the mobile layout, you did a great job! I was just confused why it changed. I'll have to keep up with the latest developments here...